# Jquery to toggle select form control disabled state?

Tags: jquery, forms, controls

I have a form with 3 dropdowns that I want to toggle the disabled state progressively. I want to disable the 2nd and 3rd dropdown initially, when the user selects an option from the 1st, the 2nd is enabled, when the 2nd option is selected I want the 3rd to be enabled.

How can  do this with jquery? Thanks

Here is the code:

```
<select name="type" id="select1" style="width:200px" onchange="populate(1);">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select Option 1</option>
<option value="first">First</option>
<option value="second">Second</option>
<option value="third">Third</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select name="make" id="select2" style="width:200px" onchange="populate(2);"disabled="disabled">
<option value="">Select Option 2</option>
<option value="first2">First</option>
<option value="second2">Second</option>
<option value="third2">Third</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
<select name="model" id="select3" style="width:200px" onchange="Go(this);"disabled="disabled">
<option value="">Select Make</option>
<option value="first3">First</option>
<option value="second3">Second</option>
<option value="third3">Third</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a simple `nextAll()` like this:

```
$('select').change(function(){ 
   $(this).nextAll('select:first:disabled').prop('disabled',false);
})
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/uFzbX/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#select1").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $("#select2").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#select2").val("");
            $("#select2").change();
        } else {
            $("#select2").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });

    $("#select2").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $("#select3").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#select3").val("");
        } else {
            $("#select3").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Working example @

> http://jsfiddle.net/djajg/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set event handlers that remove the disabling when the first two `<select>` fields are changed. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select1').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != '')
            $('#select2').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
    $('#select2').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != '')
            $('#select3').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

See a working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D8ggn/). **Note:** Using `onchange` sometimes leads to unexpected behavior in IE. You might have to use `onclick` (i.e., `.click(function())` in jQuery) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#select1').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() != "") {
        $('#select2').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#select2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
})
```

...etc.

I'm assuming you probably want to redisable the other selects if the initial state is reselected.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a slightly different approach to the others, using `index()`:

```
$('select').change(
    function(){
        var i = $(this).index('select');
        $('select').eq(i+1).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/h7EWK/).

Because you have `<br />` elements as siblings to the `select` elements, I've supplied a selector to the `index()` method, which finds the `index()` of the element according to the specified selector, rather than among all (or all sibling) elements.

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/),
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/),
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/),
- [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

Answer (score 0):

I am by *no means* a jQuery expert, so there may well be a better way to do this.  But I've written a simple function (I believe it's really a super-simple jQuery plugin) like this:

```
jQuery.fn.disabled = function (tf) {
    $('input,textarea,checkbox,select',this).attr('disabled',tf);
    if ( tf)
        this.addClass('disabled');
    else
        this.removeClass('disabled');
    return tf;
}
```

Then you can call $('#select2').disabled( false ) when select1 is selected.  I.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select1').change(function(){
        $('#select2').disabled( $(this).val() == '' );
    });
    $('#select2').change(function(){
        $('#select3').disabled( $(this).val() == '' );
    });
})
```

The advantage of the .disabled() function is twofold:
 1) It disables *and* un-disables, based on the value of the boolean passed to it, so you don't need to duplicate the "should this be enabled or disabled?" logic everywhere.
 2) It also "greys out" text, so if you wanted to wrap your  in a  or  with some descriptive text, you could call the function on the wrapping element, and the text would be greyed out, along with disabling the select (or any other input elements).

For the greyed-out text to work properly, you also need a 'disabled' class in your CSS.  Mine is quite simply:

```
.disabled {
    color: #808080;
}
```

You may want something different to match your own theme.